# Python - Passing function arguments directly to cls()

Tags: python

I came across a code snippet as follows -

```
@classmethod
def new(cls, **props):
    '''Creates a new Thread instance, ensuring a unique _id.'''
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            thread = cls(**props)
            session(thread).flush(thread)
            return thread
            ...... continued
```

The name of the class it is defined is 'Thread'. This code creates a new thread object but I'm not able to understand how this particular code is trying to do that from the code in try block.

cls is a function?

Comment: How is `new` called? What values are passed as `cls` and `props`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you've edited your question, it's clear what's happening. You're method has a the decorator [@classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=classmethod#classmethod). According to the docs:

> A class method receives the class as implicit first argument, just
>   like an instance method receives the instance. To declare a class
>   method, use this idiom:
>
> ```
> class C:
>     @classmethod
>     def f(cls, arg1, arg2, ...): ...
> ```

This is (somewhat) equivalent to this:

```
class MyClass:
    def f(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
        cls = self.__class__
        ...
```

Classes in Python are callables (e.g. they can be invoked with `Class()`). Those two things are therefore equivalent:

```
a = MyClass()
```

and

```
cls = MyClass
b = cls()
```

In summary, `cls` is not a function, but a callable. Btw. you can make any object a callable by adding the special method `__call__`:

```
class A:
    def __call__(self):
        print("Woah!")

a = A()
a()   # prints Woah!
```

Comment: What is the code 'thread = cls(**prop)' doing?  cls is not a function right?

Comment: @direwolf7: I've changed my answer. `cls()` is not a function but a callable. Functions are callables too though.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. This was new for me.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the first argument is a class and the second is a set of key-value args (see [this question describing the double star notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python)).

Inside the function the key-value args are then passed to the class constructor to make the variable thread.